# Copy data to a directory

Tags: copy, cp

I use the following command to copy data and it is working as expected.

> cp -pr --reply=yes /db-nfs/mysql3/*
>   /db-nfs/mysql5/

1) Is there a better way?

2) I want to copy the same data to /db-nfs/mysql7 as well. Is it possible in single command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are repeatedly copying the same data over to the folders rather than a one time copy to a blank target, consider using `rsync` instead:

```
rsync -av /db-nfs/mysql3/ /db-nfs/mysql5/
rsync -av /db-nfs/mysql3/ /db-nfs/mysql7/
```

(Note the trailing slashes are important!)

Answer (score 1):

1) This won't preserve hard links and extended attributes, so you may be better off using `-a` instead of `-p`.

2) Depends what you mean by a single command! You could write a script which runs multiple `cp` commands and then that script itself would be a single command.